# How to add isChecked and unChecked event for CheckBox in RecyclerView in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, checkbox, kotlin

I try to implement a OnCheckedChangeListener for checked/unchecked (checkBox) event in Android Kotlin. But it does not work. Here is my code:-

```
checkBox?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
            if (checkBox!!.isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "checked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "unCkecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
    })
```

Pic is here what i want to :- 
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9M2d.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added my own code, with help of lambda function it is possible.

```
    checkBoxSample.setOnCheckedChangeListener({
        buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            // show toast , check box is checked
        }else{
            // show toast , check box is not checked
        }
    })
```

Comment: The parenthesis is unnecessary when calling this method since in Kotlin when there is only one method in the interface, it will automatically convert it to a lambda. Then since it is a lambda and as the last parameter, parenthesis are not needed.